# Remembering variables without sessions, how does this work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, cookies

So I like to analyze websites and try to figure out how they work.

I came across this website. 
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/

They have a button that minimizes and maximizes divs. AND it remembers if you left it minimized or maximized, regardless if you're logged in or not. (it's browser specific, i.e. it only remembers based upon the brower you used.)

I see they're calling some javascript on this, but how is this done? Using cookies? I doubt it's being done with sessions since when I log in/out it doesn't affect it.

Thanks.

Comment: haven't looked at the site but cookies or other local storage is how i would do it, at least. you can set and access data entirely in js. look into the `document.cookie` and `window.localStorage` functions.

Comment: Yes.  Cookies is the most likely answer.  You can always check your browser's cookie repository, find the one they are using, and check it out, just to be sure.

Comment: Yes this can easily be achieved using cookies just set one variable to store the state of div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the cookie `forumParentToggle`. This cookie is created the first time you expand or collapse a div.

For example, if you collapse the "Classes" div, the cookie is created with the value `3354995`.

By deleting this cookie, the Classes div will be re-expanded when the page is refreshed. To the browser, it looks like you are visiting for the first time.

This cookie is referenced in the minified version of javascript they are utilizing [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/static/cms-overlay/js/build/cms.min.js).